# beautifulsoup navigating the tree

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to get string from

```
<td class="text">
```

, but by navigating from tag

```
<a name="rknjiga">
```

because it is used to target a specific section of the page. I have tried to use

```
soup.find("a", {"name": "aknjiga"}).parent
```

but that only gets me 1 level up, and my idea is to get to the first *tr* tag, one more step up the hierarchy, and then by using the .next_sibling to put pointer to next *tr* tag

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CDC5A1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDC5A1"  class="bbrownnaslov1">
        <a name="rknjiga">Poglavlja u knjizi</a> #name rknjiga is used to find section
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="92" valign="top">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="text">
                    <br/>1. Dražić, Ivan; Mujaković, Nermina.<br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text" align="right" valign="bottom">
                    <a href="#top"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text" align="right" valign="bottom">
                        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The output needs to be written in txt file in format:

1. Dražić, Ivan; Mujaković, Nermina.
2. Crnković, Dean; Mikulić Crnković, Vedrana; Rodrigues, B. G.
   ...

I'm using beautifulsoup for the first time so any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: what kind of output do you want.

Comment: I want to write it up in txt file,

Comment: based on you html, post a sample txt data, it will be helpful

Comment: txt data should look like:                                                                             1. Dražić, Ivan; Mujaković, Nermina.
2. Crnković, Dean; Mikulić Crnković, Vedrana; Rodrigues, B. G.

Comment: add to the question, this is much helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
section = soup.find('a', attrs={'name':"rknjiga"})

section.find_next('td',class_="text").get_text(strip=True)
```

out:

```
'1. Dražić, Ivan; Mujaković, Nermina.'
```

or get all the td:

```
section.find_all_next('td',class_="text")
```

> Signature: find_all_next(name, attrs, string, limit, **kwargs)
>
> Signature: find_next(name, attrs, string, **kwargs)
>
> These methods use .next_elements to **iterate over whatever tags and
>   strings that come after it** in the document. The find_all_next() method
>   returns all matches, and find_next() only returns the first match

Comment: and how would you now find the next td tag that has class text?